# TwilioQuest Javascript Lab Constant Vigilance

Tags: javascript, arrays, twilio

OBJECTIVE:
This function should take a single argument - an array of strings. Your scan function must loop through all the strings in this array, and examine each one using boolean logic.

If a string in the input array is equal to the value contraband, add the index of that item to an output array. When you have finished scanning the entire input array, return the output array, which should contain all the indexes of suspicious items in the array.

For example, given an input array of:

['contraband', 'apples', 'cats', 'contraband', 'contraband']
Your function should return the array:

[0, 3, 4]
This list contains the position inside the input array of all the contraband strings.

MY CODE:

```
function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandIndexes = [];

  freightItems.forEach(el => {
    console.log(freightItems.indexOf(el, 0));
    if (el == "contraband") {
      contrabandIndexes.push(freightItems.indexOf(el, 0));
    }
  });
  return contrabandIndexes;
}

const indexes = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Contraband Indexes: ' + indexes); // should be [1, 4]
```

I cant figure out why the index of the second 'contraband' is coming back as 1 and why I'm not getting past this level in TwilioQuest. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandIndexes = [];

  freightItems.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (el == 'contraband') {
      contrabandIndexes.push(idx);
    }
  });
  return contrabandIndexes;
}

const indexes = scan(['dog', 'contraband', 'cat', 'zippers', 'contraband']);
console.log('Contraband Indexes: ' + indexes); // should be [1, 4]
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is for searching an array:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
> can be found in the array

but `el` is an item in the array.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I didn't realize indexOf() would only return the first index of the given element! THANK YOU!